# How to solve $2\cos( \frac {\pi}3 (\theta-1)) +5=4$

Tags: trigonometry

Im having trouble with the following problem:

solve for all theta between (0 and 2pi) and find exact values where possible for:

> $$2\cos( \frac{\pi} 3(\theta-1)) +5=4$$

This is what i did:

$2\cos(\pi/3)= 1$, so

$\theta-1 = 4-5$

$\theta-1=-1$

so $\theta =0$

The answers are 3,5.

Comment: This is very hard to parse.  I am guessing you mean $\cos \left( \frac {\pi}3(\theta -1) \right)$ but who knows?

Comment: you can change it if I am wrong...

Comment: the exact question is written as: 2cosπ/3(θ−1)+5 = 4. The answer sheet says 3,5 but when I plugged it into symbolab, they answer was zero as well.

Answer (score 2):

$$2\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}(\theta-1))+5=4\to \cos(\frac{\pi}{3}(\theta-1))=-\frac{1}{2}\to \frac{\pi}{3}(\theta-1)=2k\pi\pm\frac{2\pi}{3}\\ \to \theta=6k\pm2+1$$